# How do i add syntax highlighting in Eclipse for laravel blade files

Tags: eclipse, laravel

I'm using Eclipse IDE as my main IDE for my laravel project. But I don't know how to turn on the highlighting for my blade files. How can i do it ?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it seems that Blade support is a very low priority for the Eclipse community. If you want to use a templating engine with Eclipse support, switch to Twig. If you want to use an IDE with Blade support, switch to PHPstorm.

Comment: and as many stats state laraver users are most on planet amid backenders and the laraver is in  a very hi priority . Some miracle things happen underhood, dont you think?